# How to not get stuck in an infinitely blocking function?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, blocking, nonblocking

I'm not sure what is the correct terminology to use. But my example should clear it up.

I want to listen to a [Reddit comment stream](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/subredditstream.html).

This stream receives a comment in real-time as it is posted to reddit (/r/askReddit, and /r/worldNews), so I don't have to poll the server.

However, this function is **blocking**, I need to put it into several **threads**.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#! usr/bin/python3
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import praw

def process_item(self, stream):
    # Display the comment
    for comment in stream:
        print(comment.permalink)

def get_streams(reddit):
    # Listen for comments from these two subReddits:
    streams = [
        reddit.subreddit('AskReddit').stream.comments(skip_existing=True),
        reddit.subreddit('worldnews').stream.comments(skip_existing=True)            
    ]
    pool = Pool(4)
    print('waiting for comments...')
    results = pool.map(self.process_item, streams)

    # But I want to do tons of other things down here or in `main()`.
 # The code will never reach down here because it's always listening for comments.
```

The only workaround I can see is to put my entire program logic into `process_item()`, but that seems really stupid.

I think I want `process_item` to keep adding comments to a list, ***in the background***, and then I can process those comments as I see fit. But I need to not get stuck in `process_item()`

**As the program is doing other things, a list is being queued up with jobs to do, all while the program is doing other things.**

Possible? If so, could you give me some tips as to the pattern?

I'm brand new to threading.

Comment: Just gonna throw some terms out: kafka, redis queues, pub-sub, inter-process communication. It really depends on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: But I don't see why you're putting the entire pool to work on the function, when you really just want one process/thread listening for updates

Comment: Instead of using the blocking `pool.map(...` use `pool.map_async(...`, read [multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)

Comment: Is `reddit` object thread safe? If not you may get results from one subreddit stream leaking over to another stream. You may want to create independent `reddit` object in each thread, even if you use the same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about pub/sub pattern.
if you want thread use threading module.

multiprocessing is os process. Process and threads is different things. If you want threads use threading(when process data think about GIL)

to do anything that:

you can start some threads to read data from stream and put message to LIFO data structure
start some threads to read data from LIFO data structure to process your data